# Azure App Service WebApp Graceful shutdown/Restart

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have created an ASP.Net Core 2.1 WebApp that has a single HostedService to run a background process, the process can take up to 20 seconds to complete once a cancelation token has been cancelled. This all works fine locally when run on IIS Express - the StopAsync() method is called when the IIS Express site is stopped and waits for the process to complete before the application is terminated.

When I run this app in an Azure App Service it does not shutdown or restart gracefully the StopAsync() is called but the application is killed within a few seconds not allowing the application to shutdown gracefully.

I have tried adding the following in web.config:

```
<aspNetCore shutdownTimeLimit="90" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
```

And the following in Program.cs but this had no effect:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseShutdownTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
```

Are there any other settings I need to set in an Azure App Service to increase the Shutdown timeout?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to gracefully shut down the webapp, we could inject [IApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and use the property [ApplicationStopping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime.applicationstopped?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IApplicationLifetime_ApplicationStopped) in the Startup.cs

> IApplicationLifetime is a new interface in ASP.NET Core under the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting namespace. The interface is designed to give a developer the opportunity to gracefully startup but mostly shutdown the application.

**Demo code**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
{ 
   ...
   applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);
   ...
}
private void OnShutdown()
{
   //todo
}
```

Comment: The op mentionned a HostedService for which StartAsync and StopAsync are managed internally. I am not sure I see how implementing IApplicationLifetime can help. Isn't Azure App Service able to gracefully stop the application ?